# Register custom post to woocommerce product post as product_cat type relation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a bad situation at the time, I'm exlaining you guys here.

I have wordpress with woocommerce site,

I added custom post type name "shops" and register the woocommerce product_cat with this custom post type, After registering the product_cat with shops post. Now i can assign shop under categories. Now my 2nd step is when i will add the product i will choose the shop post, that mean this product will associated to this shop like categories. Can anyone tell me what should i do in this case?

Thanks
Adil

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Should you maybe be using [Vendors](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-vendors/)

Comment: I achieve my functionality with register_taxonomy, now can you only tell me how to change woocommerce product page query to display different custom taxonomy base post, or can we add custom template between categories and product in woocommerce, example, i have shops custom post type and product_cat taxonomy is already associated with it, so i want to display shops based on product_cat after any woocommerce category then display shop related products.